# Google Cloud SQL Insert Not working?

Tags: php, google-cloud-sql

I am just starting out with Cloud SQL, so I'm sure there is a simple mistake I'm making.

I am able to connect to my Cloud instance via MySQL Workbench. I created a database and table, and was able to insert and select from this table from MySQL Workbench.

However, when I try to connect through my app engine, I am getting an error.

EDITED- Here's my code:

```
<?php
try{
    $db = null;
    $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/my-gae-appname:my-cloud-sql-instance;dbname=myschema', 'root', '');

    mysql_select_db('myschema');

    $action = $_GET["action"];
    $mapid = $_GET["mapid"];
    $src = $_GET["src"];
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO myschema.report (action, mapid, ip, source) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($action, $mapid, $ip, $src));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    echo $affected_rows;

    $db = null;

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

The error I get is:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'dpe'

Thanks!

Comment: try to add error repoting on your php `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
` and `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` below the connection

Comment: Probably because you're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_select_db` and PDO.

Comment: Usual PDO connect syntax `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);` - as per http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php - So, why are you using `mysql_select_db('myschema');`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- please see my response to Siniseus's answer.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_select_db(); has been deprecated and you should be using the class object PDO exclusively in the case. You can also use the MYSQLI class.

```
try{
$db = null;
$db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/my-gae-appname:my-cloud-sql-instance;dbname=myschema', 'root', '');

$action = $_GET["action"];
$mapid = $_GET["mapid"];
$src = $_GET["src"];
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO myschema.report (action, mapid, ip, source) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array($action, $mapid, $ip, $src));
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $affected_rows;

$db = null;

}catch(PDOException $ex){
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myschema'", but MySQL Workbench is connecting to this schema with no problem.

Comment: my apologies, but I misspelled myschema.

Comment: Yes, I accounted for that typo when I tested your suggestion. I'm still getting the same error. It's as if the schema doesn't exist, but MySQL Workbench can connect with no issues.

Comment: although mysql workbench is connecting is it selecting the schema?
Is the database highlighted on the left bar under schemas?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I switched to MySQL Api rather than PDO, and it's working fine now. Thank you.